# Time to run instructions of a for loop

Tags: c, linux

I am interested to calculate a duration of 125 μs for implementing a TDM (Time Division Multiplexing scheme) based scheme. However, I am not able to get this duration with an accuracy of +-5us using the Linux operating system. I am using DPDK which runs on ubuntu and intel hardware. If I take time from the computer using function `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)`, it adds the time to make a call to the kernel to get the time. This gives an inaccurate duration to me.

Therefore, I dedicated a cpu core for calculating time without asking the time from the kernel. For this, I run a for loop for a maximum instructions (8000000) and find the number instructions that need to be executed for the 125 μs duration (i.e. (`125*8000000)/timespent`).

However, the problem is that it is also giving inaccurate results (there is always different results i.e., a difference 1000 instructions).

- Does anybody know why I am getting inaccurate results even if I am dedicating a CPU for this?
- Do you know a method to calculate a duration (very short, may be equal to 125 us) without making a call to the kernel? thanks!

Comment: Burning clock cycles to generate a delay is not reliable on modern CPUs, for a variety of reasons. Besides which, if you need accuracy/reliability for this then you will need to use a proper real-time OS.

Comment: Hi Paul,  thanks for the info. could you please elaborate this? How to make the call to the proper real-time OS".

Comment: OS = Operating System - consider either a real-time Linux kernel or VxWorks or similar. Before that you need to define your real-time requirements though, i.e. what accuracy/reliability do you need for your timing etc ?

Comment: I need the accuracy of 5us (+or -). The problem is that if I make a call to the Linux kernel, the kernel at that time may be busy in doing some other task (which may reduce accuracy). Therefore, if a kernel independent function exists or if I dedicate a CPU to calculate the time, it will be useful in calculating a small duration like 125 us (without an error).

Comment: See @FrancoisGirard's answer below - you just can't do accurate/reliable timing on a general-purpose OS. Use a real-time OS, or if you have a choice about what hardware you use for this project then consider using an embedded micro-controller with a fixed clock speed and no OS to get in the way.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the clarification!

Comment: No problem - I've added a `linux` tag to the question since this seems to be what you're using. You might also want to add some background info to your question, e.g. why you need an accurate measurement of 125 µs - there may be alternative solutions if you explain the wider problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I need this accuracy for implementing a TDM (Time Division Multiplexing scheme) based scheme. However, I am not able to achieve this accuracy using the Linux operating system. I am using DPDK which runs on ubuntu and intel hardware.

Comment: Hit the [edit] link in order to add useful background info such as this to your question.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this outside of dedicated hardware, driver and/or an RTOS?  A hardware timer and it's interrupt can guarantee response in 125 +- 5us if given a high enough interrupt priority.

Comment: @Paul, Can I get the required accuracy, if I install real time kernel on the ubuntu, as suggested in this post (http://askubuntu.com/questions/72964/how-can-i-install-a-realtime-kernel)

Comment: I would hope so, but you'll want to do some research first to be sure. You'll need to write your code carefully to ensure you meet your real-time constraints too. Start reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTLinux

Comment: Thanks Paul! I will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting inaccurate result because you are on a multitasking operating system. You cannot do this on modern computers. You can only do this on embedded microcontroller where you control 100% of the cpu time. The operating system need to manage your process, even if you have a dedicated cpu. The mouse and keyboard takes time also. Your have to run the process on 'Bare Metal'.

Comment: How do you know? does he name his enviroment?!

Comment: Also "modern computers" the behaving of hardware has no relation to its age or technique level.

Comment: Why the down-vote ? The OP has already said he's using Linux, so it's perfectly correct to point out that reliable timing with 5 µs accuracy is unfeasible.

Comment: Do you mean to say that even if I dedicate a CPU to perform a task (such as running for loop for 800000 times), 100% CPU will not be dedicated to this task, even if  no other task is assigned to that CPU.

Comment: @Zaibis: the "modern computers" aspect is certainly valid - older CPUs didn't have e.g. dynamic frequency scaling, which makes timing using instruction clock cycles unreliable.

Comment: I don't dissaggree with that, but you are just assuming same as I do. and answering questions based on assumptions is not the goal of SE. You should clear it out with OP. If you let OP clarify his enviroment by an edit or you target the fact of a assumption in your answer I will undo my downvote and maybe even upvote.

Comment: @Zaibis: OP has already said he's using Linux - did you miss that part ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Probably 99.999% will be dedicated, a small amount is used byt the OS itself

Comment: @Paul R: yes I do, even now I cant find it. And "modern computers" sounds like a overall limit to me. but even a modern computer constructed for such purposes can behave like that. thats what i eman

Comment: @Zaibis: OP's question is quite vague, I agree, but if you read the comments he says "... if I make a call to the Linux kernel ..."

Comment: @Paul R yeah got it. In my second reading I just checked the OP again and by refreshing new comments I have overseen that. But I undownvoted allready.

Comment: You can do this on almost anything, given hardware timer/counter connected to an interrupt of high enough priority and a suitable driver.